# How to use the gradle jib plugin to push an image to the google cloud Container Registry

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform, jib

How to use the gradle jib plugin to push an image to the google cloud Container Registry

I am trying to deploy a simple Spring-Boot application and deploy it using google cloud and the Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE). I am also following the [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-springboot-kubernetes?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Flearn%2Fpathways%2Fspringboot-google-cloud%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fcloud-springboot-kubernetes#0), however the tutorial uses maven and I want to try using gradle for my project. I am able to build my own docker image as well as run the docker image within google's cloud shell, but I cannot seem to figure out how to push the image to the container registry.

The maven command the tutorial gives is

```
./mvnw -DskipTests com.google.cloud.tools:jib-maven-plugin:build -Dimage=gcr.io/$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT/hello-java:v1
```

I have tried to use the gradle version, but something is wrong and I can't figure out what it is, as well as trying some instructables from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/introducing-jib-build-java-docker-images-better).

```
./gradlew build com.google.cloud.tools.jib:build -Dimage=gcr.io/$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT/hello-java:v3
```

I don't think I need to add the plugin in my build.gradle file but I could be wrong, I am new to using the jib tool.

I then would be able to run the image with the following

```
docker run -ti --rm -p 8080:8080 gcr.io/$GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT/hello-java:v1
```

The repo I am wanting to deploy from is located [here](https://github.com/roschwartz79/Google-Cloud-Playground)

As a secondary question, is it possible to publish images to the google cloud container registry from my local development environment, or do I have to push images to the registry via the Google Cloud Shell?

Comment: Does this [doc](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#quickstart) help you more?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I have looked at that doc and I have tried followed it. I have the plugin and the "jib.to.image" path configured. Now when I run the gradle jibDockerBuild command I get an error that the Spring-Boot plugin requires a specific version of gradle, an error that did not come up if I just ran it locally in the Cloud Shell.

Comment: The Spring Boot plugin requiring a specific version seems like an issue with the Spring Boot plugin, unrelated to Jib.

Answer (score 2):

Update: I figured it out- I don't have to use jib although I would like to figure this out in the future. I am going to play around with my gradle configurations to see if that is a possible issue, but I am using Gradle 6.3 so I don't think that is the problem.

From my built docker image I can just use a docker push command like so

```
docker push gcr.io/<application-name>/<image-name>:<tag>
```

And my image shows up in the container registry after I allow access to the registry from the cloud shell.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-gradle-plugin#using-google-container-registry-gcr documents how to this in recent versions of JIB.

BTW watch https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/issues/3545 for adding documentation about how to push to Google Cloud Container Registry using Google Cloud Build.